# How can I automate tests to check correctness of a JSF application?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jsf, web-applications

I wanted to know ways of checking my jsf application in terms of functioning and performance.
Kindly guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) to test any kind of web-app.

Comment: i am using firefox 4.0.1 so selenium is basically not installing on it.. Kindly suggest